# Trying to send commands via Subprocess to operate with ffmpeg

Tags: python, shell, command-line, ffmpeg, subprocess

I am trying to build a script that converts video files via ffmpeg inside Python 3. 
Via Windows PowerShell I successfully obtained the desired result via the following command:

```
ffmpeg -i test.webm -c:v libx264 converted.mp4
```

However, if I try to repeat the same operation inside python via the following code:

```
import subprocess
from os import getcwd

print(getcwd()) # current directory
subprocess.call(["ffmpeg", " -f test.webm -c libx264 converted.mp4"])
```

I get the following error:

```
Output #0, mp4, to ' -f test.webm -c libx264 converted.mp4':
Output file #0 does not contain any stream
```

I am in the correct folder where the files are. Do you have better methods to execute commands in shell via Python? That should preferably work on different platforms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
import shlex

cmd = shlex.split("ffmpeg -f test.webm -c libx264 converted.mp4")
subprocess.call(cmd)
```

you need pass each argument as a single element in a list, that's how argv works, or let shell do the split:

```
subprocess.call("ffmpeg -f test.webm -c libx264 converted.mp4", shell=True)
```

Comment: Brilliant. Had to pass the arguments directly as a list to make it work. Your code chunk is interpreted as a list of lists and return an error.
This is the final version: import subprocess
    import shlex
    args = shlex.split("ffmpeg -i test.webm -c:v libx264 converted.mp4 -y")
    subprocess.call(args)